Prove that object is allocating each time / Prove that object is not cached or singleton
I have loop where I initialize new object. For example
let count = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    const objectExample = new SomeObject()
}

SomeObject is object from external library.
I don't have access to loop statement, only to file, where SomeObject is intialize.
I want to check is SomeObject singleton or have mechanizsm of caching, without checking source code (sometimes it just not readable).
I guess Nodejs does not provide functions to get address of object allocation, so I don't know from where I can start.

Please don't embed tags in the title of the question, unless they are organic to the conversational tone of the title. I've removed it now, but keep this in mind for the future.

@somethinghere a constructor can use return to return any arbitrary object, not necessarily a new instance: https://jsbin.com/fefatabonu/1/edit?js,console

Please, explain your case and your constraints further.  Basically it's new SomeObject === new SomeObject  check. I don't see a problem with instantiating a class for debugging purposes
